# Publishing datasets as a journal articles

Tags: journals, paper-submission

We have created an NLP dataset out of written texts of a certain group of people.

I thought perhaps we can publish the dataset as a journal paper (the data is an external appendix to the article and published somewhere on the internet).

*Data in Brief* and *Nature Scientific Data* publish such articles. However *Data in Brief* charges $600 and *Nature* has a very high quality expectancy.

Are there other journals where we can publish our NLP data sets?

Comment: If you are grant funded, the $600 seems a small matter.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not, and a full professor's monthly salary is $350 in my country. Yet Data in Brief does not have any discount for my country.

Comment: Some journals will waive fees in some circumstances. You might ask.

Answer (score 1):

If I search on *Web of Science* for `TOPIC: (natural language processing) AND DOCUMENT TYPES: (Data Paper)`, then I find various results from *Scientific Data* (which you mentioned already), one from *BMC Bioinformatics*, one from *Bioinformatics*, and one from the *International Journal of Robotics Research*.

- *BMC Bioinformatics* asks for APCs of $2490.00, but [offers waivers on a case-by-case basis](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/submission-guidelines/fees-and-funding).
- *Bioinformatics*: I did not find any information about APCs (though, according to their [Instructions](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/instructions_for_authors#Page%20Charges), they charge for OA licenses, for colour figures, and for excess pages).
- *International Journal of Robotics Research*: I did not find any information about APCs - but to be sure, have a careful look at their [submission guidelines](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/journal/international-journal-robotics-research#submission-guidelines).

By the way, *Data in Brief* also offers reduced APCs or even total waivers under special circumstances ([see here](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/data-in-brief/2352-3409/open-access-journal)).